# How can i make shortcut for pydoc?

Tags: python-3.x, vim, pydoc

I'm trying to add vim shorcut for pydoc.

I use this shortcut now.

```
nnoremap <buffer> K : <C-u>execute "!python3 -m pydoc " . expand("<cword>")<CR>
```

But this shortcut doesn't work with downloaded library.

Example, it works at `os.listdir` and doens't work at `np.zeros`

So I type `:python3 -m pydoc numpy.zeros` to find document of numpy.zeros.

How should I fix my shortcut to work like `:$myshortcut numpy.zeros`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
I download this [code](https://github.com/fs111/pydoc.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/python_pydoc.vim)

and I fixed a line to use with python3

```
let g:pydoc_cmd = 'python3 -m pydoc'
```

Thanks.